# Racket recursive variable?

Tags: recursion, racket

Fig. 65 in "How to Design Programs" is as follows:

```
; Nelon -> Number
; determines the smallest number on l
(define (inf l)
  (cond
    [(empty? (rest l)) (first l)]
    [else
     (local ((define smallest-in-rest (inf (rest l))))
       (cond
         [(< (first l) smallest-in-rest) (first l)]
         [else smallest-in-rest]))]))
```

Can somebody explain how variable smallest-in-rest works. I get recursion in a function but a variable has me confused

Answer (score 1):

It's just a shorthand (longhand ;-)) for the following:

```
(let ((smallest-in-rest (inf (rest l))))
  (cond
    [(< (first l) smallest-in-rest) (first l)]
    [else smallest-in-rest]))
```

The `let` should make it clear that we're just storing the result of the `(inf (rest l))` so that it only has to be written once in the code, rather than once for each branch of the `cond`.

Comment: Wonder why racket goes to such lengths to teach students something completely different than their main language. It's like teaching JavaScript by first teaching them Python..

Comment: The HtDP curriculum [is not about learning Racket (or any language)](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_preface.html#%28part._.Dr.Racket_and_the_.Teaching_.Languages%29). As the first line of the book says, any idiot can pick up any language in a few days. HtDP teaches how to program, a significantly harder undertaking. It uses a series of streamlined beginner languages to do so, which allows students to focus on what's important, and not on idiosyncrasies of syntax (think `public static void main`).

Comment: As someone who learned `local` first, it made more sense to me over `let`, because we could reuse the same syntax for definitions that we had already learned. We spent less time learning about syntax that way.